# Elevate rights for Administrator that is running in UAC mode

Tags: c#, uac

I have a .NET executable that starts a Windows service (through ServiceController). The problem is that this does not work when in UAC mode.

The manifest file says "asInvoker".

What is the best way to get a similar prompt as in Windows or "accept" just like in the prompt when starting/stopping service manually?

Comment: Change it to asAdministrator, as per the comment there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force my .NET App to run as administrator on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)